# Copying files and folders of only batch and vbs script files over network

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am in the process migrating my servers from 2003 to 2008 and trying to write a powershell script that will copy all files that are vbs and bat from the 2003 server to the 2008 server and also keep the folder structure in tact as it is vital for the program to run.

Here is what i have so far.  It works kinda.  it will create the `D:\folder` on the new servers but it will not copy anything over.  It also creates the `log.txt` with all of the names of the vbs and bat files and there paths.

```
New-PSDrive -name source -PSProvider FileSystem -root "\\servername\d$\folder" |Out-Null

$targetdirectory = "d:\folder"
$sourcedirectory = "\\servername\d$\folder"

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedirectory -filter "*.bat","*.vbs" -Recurse| Out-File D:\log.txt
if ( -Not (Test-Path $targetdirectory)) {New-Item -path $targetdirectory -Type Directory | out-null } 
Copy-Item -Path $sourcedirectory -filter "*.bat","*.vbs" -Destination $targetdirectory -recurse -force 


remove-psdrive -name source
```

The part that is not working is this

```
Copy-Item -Path $sourcedirectory -filter "*.bat","*.vbs" -Destination $targetdirectory -recurse -force
```

I just changed it to

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedirectory -Include "*.bat","*.vbs" -Recurse| Out-File D:\log.txt
if ( -Not (Test-Path $targetdirectory)) {New-Item -path $targetdirectory -Type Directory | out-null } 
Copy-Item -Path $sourcedirectory -Include *.bat, *.vbs -Destination $targetdirectory -recurse -force
```

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated as i am on a huge deadline and am stuck

Comment: Welcome to SO! This website is about answering questions, and even though you told us where you are, we need to know what doesn't work to help you (as SO isn't about coding for you, well, we could, but not for free ^^). So, in the next step, what doesn't work?

Comment: How about [Using PowerShell and Bits](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/08/25/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-and-bits-to-simplify-downloading-large-files.aspx) the only problem is, I'm not 100% sure that would work for subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use robocopy.

```
robocopy source dest *.vbs *.bat /s
```

Comment: robocopy is not an option per my boss otherwise i would.

Comment: Seems like a strange limitation.It's what I've used for a lot of file server migrations. Anyway, look at Copy-Item. something like Copy-Item -recurse -path "source"  -Destination "dest" -Include "*.vbs","*.bat" -Container

Comment: Looking at your edit, you're missing the -container switch on your Copy-Item.

Comment: would that do all sub folders also?  right now it is just doing the d:\folder not d:\folder\folder and so on as there are many sub folders.

Comment: OK so it is only copying any .bat or .vbs in the root folder and ignoring any subfolders.

Comment: So it looks like copy-item doesn't work recursively if you filter. The best tool for the job is robocopy (and for most bulk copying needs) but if you can't use that, I found this - http://techblog.dorogin.com/2013/01/powershell-recursively-copy-folder-structure.html

Comment: Thanks! I am trying the exclude of just certain files over 2MB in size to see  if this works and so far it is, but would rather just copy over the other files and thats it as it is faster :)

Comment: You don't have to use exclude. You could change that to include instead. Its just an example of iterating through each file to copy it.

Comment: When i try include it just copies anything in the root directory and that is it.  with and without -recurse.  I have no idea what is going on why it isnt doing any subfolders.

Comment: You need to go through the rest of what's at that link, not just use include. Essentially using GCI and then piping each file to something that will copy it. It's all in that link.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments from the other answer it just looks like you are having an issue filtering certain files for use with `Copy-Item` yes? In most cases you will see suggestions of using `Get-ChildItem` to isolate the files you want and piping to `Copy-Item`. You are *almost* already doing this.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedirectory -filter "*.bat","*.vbs" -Recurse
$files | Out-File D:\log.txt
$files | Copy-Item -Destination $targetdirectory -Force
```

`$files` contains which files you wanted to isolate (You could pipe it into `Where-Object` to get files of a certain size if need be.). Take files and output the results to an external txt file (Using `Export-CSV` can make for cleaner output of object FYI). Then we simply pipe it into `Copy-Item`. No need to try and file again.

Comment: I have tried that and it is also failing.  I am not trying pulling the direct paths from one csv file and copying them to the paths listed in another csv file and that doesnt work either.  This is frustrating.

Comment: @ScottBruhn We should be able to get through this but know that _it is also failing_ does not help me at all debug your issue. Also, you have no reference to CSV in your question so I don't understand the pertinence of bringing it up now. How is this failing exactly?